# Best place for SVG symbols location in an HTML5 document that uses CSS Grid?

Tags: html, svg

In an HTML5 document that uses SVG elements, where is the best place to put SVG symbol definitions?

The SVG container is like a script or a stylesheet in that it is a non-visible element but it does not belong in the document 'head'.

It also isn't really part of 'header', 'main' or 'footer'. Besides, if I place it in the 'footer'.

I am using HTML5 CSS Grid with the document body tag as 'grid'. Therefore I don't want it to be deemed as a grid item, to throw out my page layout.

I need inline SVGs so I can't put it in a graphics file outside my document.

I am keen for the document outline to be good with my document semantically correct in order to facilitate this.

Where is the best place for my SVG symbol definitions?

Comment: I use to create an SVG element at the top of the `<body>` in my document. This svg element may be very small and/or may have `display:none`. In this svg element I have a `<defs>` and inside the `<defs>` I have all the symbols. If this svg have `display:none` it won't interfere with the grid, however it is better to create an other element inside the body for your grid

Comment: @enxaneta does 'display:none' on an SVG element have to be an inline style? I have inline CSS in the `<head>` and my SVGs that use the symbols are not showing. Oddly enough I also forgot the `<body>` tag in my document, so thanks for your answer. So now I have the SVG symbols set to width: 0, height: 0, at the top of the body. I placed the symbols in between the header and the body, Chrome dev tools then show it moved to body. Same if I place them in head. So I think your answer is a good one!